# Duplicity doesn't like max open files setting on Mavericks

Tags: macos, ulimit, duplicity

I use duplicity to backup some files. I'm now trying to restore to my Mac to test the backup, but get the following error:

```
> duplicity me@backupserver.io/backup_dr ~/restored_files
Max open files of 256 is too low, should be >= 1024.
Use 'ulimit -n 1024' or higher to correct.
```

So I try:

```
sudo ulimit -n 1024
```

And it seems fine, then run:

```
> ulimit -a
...
open files                      (-n) 256
...
```

How do you actually get the limit to change? I've Google'd with no luck :(

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. 
Turns out this works under bash, but not in tcsh.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ulimit -n 1024` without sudo. For some reason it didn't work with sudo for me.
If it says `Operation not permitted` try closing and opening another terminal.